# Print header to file just once

Tags: python-3.x

```
 def x(filename, saved):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fin, \
         open(saved, 'w') as fout:
        header = next(fin, '\n')
        for line in fin:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            fields = line.split(',')
            fields_new = header + line
            if float(fields[1]) <= float(fields[2]):
                print(fields_new, file=fout)
```

The problem is when I print I get the header repeated every time, like so:

```
header
line
header
line
etc..
```

instead of

```
header
line
line
line
```

How can I make the header only appear once?

Comment: Instead of printing "fields_new" print "fields" within the loop.

Comment: Well, don't add `header` to `fields_new` in each loop - print it just once before you start looping through the rest of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
def x(filename, saved):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fin, \
         open(saved, 'w') as fout:
        header = next(fin, '\n')
        print(header, file=fout)
        for line in fin:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            fields = line.split(',')
            if float(fields[1]) <= float(fields[2]):
                print(line, file=fout)
```